# To generate a MS docx file in Swift

Tags: swift, python-docx

I am trying to generate the MS document with format docx in Swift. Because there is no direct approach to do, I am thinking use Python module "python-docx".

My swift workaround is swift version 5.1-dev(LLVM 200186e28b, Swift 1238976565) in Ubuntu 18.04 version.

From the sample code in python-docx website https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```py
table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=3)
hdr_cells = table.rows[0].cells
hdr_cells[0].text = 'Id'
hdr_cells[1].text = 'Quantity'
hdr_cells[2].text = 'Description'
```

Swift code was like written in:

```swift
let document = Python.import("docx")
let doc = document.Document
let inches = document.shared.Inches

let pydoc = doc()

let table = pydoc.add_table(rows:1, cols:3)
let cells = table.rows[0].cells
```

my problem is how to change the line "hdr_cells[0].text = "Id" of python to Swift?

I have tried to write it by:

```
let hdr_cells[0].text = "Id" and get errors. 
error: consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
error: type annotation missing in pattern
let hdr_cells[0].text = "Id"
error: value of type '[Int]' has no member 'text'
let hdr_cells[0].text = "Id"
```

Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: `let cells = table.rows[0].cells`
`cells[0].text = "Id"`

Comment: __life hack:__ you can create an HTML file with a CSS and add the extension `.docx` to it, then MS Office will open it smoothly without any problem – no one will suspect a thing – unless you'd need to utilise any specific feature of word-precessing which can't be added into an HTML file, but otherwise you'd be just alright.

Comment: @ndreisg It works. Thanks.

Comment: @holex Thanks for your comment. I'll try it.